# Looking for RESTful approach to update multiple resources with the same field set

Tags: rest

The task: I have multiple resources that need to be updated in one HTTP call.

The resource type, field and value to update are the same for all resources.

Example: have set of cars by their IDs, need to update "status" of all cars to "sold".

Classic RESTFul approach: use request URL something like
**PUT /cars**
with JSON body like
**[{id:1,status:sold},{id:2,status:sold},...]**

However this seems to be an overkill: too many times to put **status:sold**

Looking for a RESTful way (I mean the way that is as close to "standard" rest protocol as possible) to send **status:sold** just once for all cars along with the list of car IDs to update. This is what I would do:

**PUT /cars**
With JSON
**{ids=[1,2,...],status:sold}** but I am not sure if this is truly RESTful approach.

Any ideas?

Also as an added benefit: I would like to be able to avoid JSON for small number of cars by simply setting up a URL with parameters something like this:

**PUT /cars?ids=1,2,3&status=sold**

Is this RESTful enough?

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler way would just be:

```
{sold:[1,2,...]}
```

There's no need to have multiple methods for larger or smaller numbers of requests - it wastes development time and has no noteable impact upon performance or bandwidth.

As far as it being RESTful goes, as long as it's easily decipherable by the recipient and contains all the information you need, then there's no problem with it.

Comment: "as long as it's easily decipherable by the recipient" - well, I might have something like **POST /cars/update?ids=1,2,3&status=sold** and it is simplest anybody could ever get. But is it really RESTful?

Comment: No, as you're using GET variables to change data on the server, rather than just to "GET" it. http://ajaxpatterns.org/RESTful_Service#RESTful_Principles provides better information regarding the generally accepted standards.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it using put is not sufficient to write a single property of a resource. One idea is to simply expose the property as a resource itself:

Therefore: PUT /car/carId/status with body content 'Sold'.

Updating more than one car should result in multiple puts since a request should only target a single resource.

Another Idea is to expose a certain protocol where you build a 'batch' resource.

POST /daily-deals-report/ body content {"sold" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

Then the system can simply acknowledge the deals being made and update the cars status itself. This way you create a whole new point of view and enable a more REST like api then you actually intended.

Also you should think about exposing a resource listing all cars that are available and therefore are ready for being sold (therefore not sold, and not needing repairs or are not rent).

GET /cars/pricelist?city=* -> List of all cars ready to be sold including car id and price.

This way a car do not have a status regarding who is owning the car. A resource is usually independent of its owner (owner is aggregating cars not a composite of it).

Whenever you have difficulties to map an operation to a resource your model tend to be flawed by object oriented thinking. With resources many relations (parent property) and status properties tend to be misplaced since designing resources is even more abstract than thinking in services.

If you need to manipulate many similar objects you need to identify the business process that triggers those changes and expose this process by a single resource describing its input (just like the daily deals report).